# Derivative of the floor function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x) = x^2\lfloor x \rfloor $.

How can I find its derivative? I understand that because of the discontinuities at the integers, it does not admit a derivative at those points.  However, for non-integers, I have tried using the definition of a derivative but I cannot come to a conclusion.

Comment: For non-integers there's a neighbourhood where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n<x<n+1$ then $f(x)=x^2n$ so
$$f'(x)=2xn=2x\lfloor x\rfloor.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The floor function is constant away from the discontinuous points you mentioned earlier.

$f'(x)=2x⌊x⌋$

Comment: and at thhose discontinuous points ? 
$$f'(x) = 2 x \lfloor x \rfloor + x^2 \sum_n \delta(x-n)$$